# Airflow create new tasks based on task return value

Tags: python, airflow

How can I get xcom from an airflow task and create other tasks using theses values.
Per exemple:

```
def func_test():
    return ['task_2', 'task_3']

with DAG(
    'dag_name',
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 4, 19),
    catchup=False,
    default_args= {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0
    }
) as dag:

    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='func_test',
        python_callable=func_test,
        provide_context=True
    )

    for task in task_1.output:
        new_tasks = PythonOperator(
            task_id=task,
            python_callable=another_function,
            provide_context=True
        )
```

The expected result that I'm trying to achieve is two new tasks based on the return value of task 1.

Is it possible to create new tasks based on a return of a function?

Comment: What version of Airflow are you on?  AFAIK this is only possible via the relatively new [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) feature introduced in v2.3.0.

Comment: I'm using the version 2.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamic task mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) was introduced in Airflow 2.3 to support this use case. While you can use "classic" Airflow operators, I suggest using dynamic task mapping in combination with the TaskFlow API, which makes it a lot easier:

```py
import datetime

from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import DAG

with DAG(
    "dag_name",
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 19),
    catchup=False,
    default_args={"depends_on_past": False, "retries": 0},
) as dag:

    @task
    def func_test():
        return ["task_2", "task_3"]

    @task
    def another_function(input_value):
        print(input_value)

    another_function.expand(input_value=func_test())
```

Your graph view will look as follows:

[image]

`another_function` shows `[2]`, indicating two tasks were generated/run.

When using the TaskFlow API, the output from `func_test` is automatically stored as an XCom and used as input for the `another_function` task. `expand()` tells Airflow to generate a task for each element in the given collection, which in this case is the output of `func_test`.